# Issues with JavaScript function output not persisting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a portion of my code. Math and everything is working correctly. My issue is when the 'to submit' button is clicked. It runs through this code, all of the variables and inputs are saved correctly. My issue is that my outputs, 'Payment" and "pi" display on the website for a frame before the page are reloaded. Is there a way to make the output stay as well as the inputs the user puts into the fields?

```
<div id="div7" class="square">
            <h1 padding-top="20px">Loan Information</h1>
            <form>

                <div class="col-25">Years</div><div class="col-75"><input type="number" id="years" min="0"></div><br>

                <div class="col-25">Interest</div><div class="col-75"><input type="number" id="rate" min="0"></div><br>

                <div class="col-25">Loan Amount</div><div class="col-75"><input type="number" id="amount" min="0"></div><br>

                <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>   
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">

                <h1 padding-top="25px">Loan Details</h1><br>
                <div class="col-25">Monthly Payment</div><div class="col-75">:<output id="payment"></output></div><br>

                <div class="col-25">P/I</div><div class="col-75">:<output id="pi"</output></div><br>


            </form>

        </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction(){

            amt=eval(document.getElementById("amount").value);


            yrs=eval(document.getElementById("years").value)*12;

            rte=eval(document.getElementById("rate").value)/1200;
            pmt=(rte+(rte/(Math.pow((1+rte),(yrs))-1)))*amt;
            pmt=pmt*100;
            mpt=Math.round(pmt);
            pmt = pmt/100;
            pi = (pmt*yrs)*100;
            pi = Math.round(pi);
            pi=pi/100;
            document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = payment ;
            document.getElementById("pi").innerHTML = pi;


        }



    </script>
```

Comment: why are you using eval() ?

Comment: `sessionStorage`, `localStorage`, Cookies, hidden variables set by the backend, url query strings; various ways to preserve data between page loads

Comment: Not sure, but it works, my concern is with the outputs though.

Comment: You should be using parseFloat, Number, parseInt to convert a string to a number, not eval.

Answer (score 0):

change your:

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>`

to:

`<button onclick="return myFunction()">Calculate</button>`

also, note that you are not defining any variables, it will make your code unmaintainable in the future, everything that you are creating is global.

here you have a working example, please note that I had to define the `payment` value because it was not defined.

```js
function myFunction(e) {

  //payment was not define so I'll just leave a 100 :)
  payment = 100;
  amt = eval(document.getElementById("amount").value);


  yrs = eval(document.getElementById("years").value) * 12;

  rte = eval(document.getElementById("rate").value) / 1200;
  pmt = (rte + (rte / (Math.pow((1 + rte), (yrs)) - 1))) * amt;
  pmt = pmt * 100;
  mpt = Math.round(pmt);
  pmt = pmt / 100;
  pi = (pmt * yrs) * 100;
  pi = Math.round(pi);
  pi = pi / 100;
  console.log(payment)
  document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = payment;
  document.getElementById("pi").innerHTML = pi;

  return false;

}
```

```html
<div id="div7" class="square">
  <h1 padding-top="20px">Loan Information</h1>
  <form>

    <div class="col-25">Years</div>
    <div class="col-75"><input type="number" id="years" min="0"></div><br>

    <div class="col-25">Interest</div>
    <div class="col-75"><input type="number" id="rate" min="0"></div><br>

    <div class="col-25">Loan Amount</div>
    <div class="col-75"><input type="number" id="amount" min="0"></div><br>

    <button onclick="return myFunction()">Calculate</button>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    <h1 padding-top="25px">Loan Details</h1><br>
    <div class="col-25">Monthly Payment</div>
    <div class="col-75">:<output id="payment"></output></div><br>

    <div class="col-25">P/I</div>
    <div class="col-75">:<output id="pi" </output></div><br>


  </form>

</div>
```